# Is there an elliptic regularity for the whole space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a $W^{2,p}$ estimate or $C^{2,\alpha}$ estimate for Poisson equations in the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$? That is, suppose $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n),1<p\leq\infty(\in C^{\alpha})$, and $\Delta u=f \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n$. Do we have $u\in W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)(\in C^{2,\alpha})$ ? And for more general elliptic equations? Any counterexamples or reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should look in Gilbarg-Trudinger. Chapter 9 does the $L^p$ estimates, and I think Chapter 4 does the Holder regularity estimates for the Poisson equation - chapter 6 does the more general Schauder estimates.