# Self adjointness of an elliptic differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $A:D(a)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be an elliptic partial differential operator
$$
A(f)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}\partial_{x_j}(a_{ij}(x)\partial_{x_i}f)
$$
where $a_{ij}\in C^{\infty}_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$, this means they are bounded continuously differentiable functions with bounded derivative of all orders.
Assume that there is a $c>0$ such that for every $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}(x)y_iy_j>c|y|^2,\ \text{for every $x$.}
$$
Assume also that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.
The question is how to prove that, on the domain $D(A)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the operator $A$ is selfadjoint.

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: If you content yourself with proving that the operator is *symmetric*, then you just need to use integration by parts as Shuhao Cao suggests. If you need to prove that the operator is *self-adjoint* you may try using the basic criterion of self-adjointness, which you may find [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/), Proposition 3.

Comment: I know that symmetry follows by integration by parts as Shuhao Cao suggests but the problem is to show that it is self-adjoint. I will try to see if I can show the basic criterium for selfadjointness thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

We recall definitions first. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. A linear operator $A\colon D(A)\subset H\to H$ is said to be *symmetric* if 
\begin{equation}
(Af, g)=(f, Ag),\qquad \forall f, g\in D(A),
\end{equation}
and it is said to be *self-adjoint* if
\begin{equation}
D(A)=D(A^\star)\quad \text{and}\quad (Af, g)=(f, Ag),\quad \forall f,g\in D(A).
\end{equation}
Here $D(A^\star)$ is the biggest domain on which the adjoint operator $A^\star$ can be defined, that is 
\begin{equation}
D(A^\star)=\left\{g\in H\ |\ \text{the map }f\in D(A)\mapsto (Af, g)\ \text{is a continuous linear functional}\right\}\end{equation}
A self-adjoint operator is necessarily *closed*, meaning that its graph $\{(f, Af)\in D(A)\times H\}$ is a closed subset of $H\times H$. This is equivalent to the fact that $D(A)$ is a Banach space when equipped with the graph norm 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{G(A)}=\lVert f\rVert+\lVert Af\rVert,\qquad f\in D(A).$$

To prove that a symmetric operator is self-adjoint one can use the following criterion, named *basic criterion of self-adjointess* on Reed & Simon's *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics*, volume I, Theorem VIII.3.

**Theorem**. Let $A$ be symmetric. Then the following three statements are equivalent:

1. $A$ is self-adjoint;
2. $A$ is closed and $\ker(A^\star\pm i)=\{0\}$;
3. $A\pm i$ are both surjective.

We will show that the operator $A$ given in the question is self-adjoint by proving that it satisfies property 2. First of all we note that $A$ is closed, because from elliptic regularity theory (see for example Evans's book on PDE, 2nd edition, §6.3.5) we have for the graph norm 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{G(A)}=\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}+\lVert Af\rVert_{L^2}\ge C\lVert f\rVert_{H^2},\qquad \forall f\in D(A),$$
so a $\lVert\cdot \rVert_{G(A)}$-Cauchy sequence is a $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{H^2}$-Cauchy sequence also and $D(A)$ is a Banach space with the graph norm. We now turn to the equation
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
(A^\star + i)f=0.
\end{equation}
We claim that any $f\in D(A^\star)$ satisfying \eqref{1} is necessarily null. Indeed, again by regularity theory we can observe that $f\in C^\infty$. So 
\begin{equation}
0=(A^\star+i)f=(A+i)f,
\end{equation}
and because of symmetry we have $\lVert (A+i)f\rVert_{L^2}^2=\lVert Af\rVert_{L^2}^2+\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}^2$, from which we conclude that $f\equiv 0$. We have thus proved that $A$ satisfies all properties of the basic criterion of self-adjointness.

Comment: Dear Giuseppe Negro, thank you very much for your solution, however there is something I don't understand yet. Evans's estimates work on bounded domains, however the operator is on $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Are those estimates valid in that context?

Comment: Yes, the estimates you see on Evans's book are valid on the whole space too. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/373342/8157) for some references. The proof should be much easier because you do not have to worry about the boundary, but I haven't performed the computation yet.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro are (uniformly) parabolic Differential operators closed also?

Comment: @CSA: You should specify a domain, to ask about closedness. Anyway, I don't know, but I would be surprised if they were not closed on their "natural" domains (whatever they might be).

Comment: Do you know of a good reference, I was looking in the Evans one your provided for the elliptic PDEs case.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/spectral-theory-and-differential-operators/93D1D33A1395B4BA34C81CF615E21EF6